# undefined method error rails 3 sunspot search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I can not figure out how to fix this issue!!! Please help!!

```
"undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass"
```

results with the following code:

```
<ul>Test Search:
    <% @optsolr.each do |c| %>
      <li>
    <%= c.description %>
      </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

When I only call "c" instead of c.description the result is:
Test Search:

```
   " [#<Nmodel id: 44, name: nil, price: nil, expiration: "2012-02-22", category: "Life ",      description: "my description text", user_id: 3, created_at: "2012-02-22 04:20:48", updated_at: "2012-02-22 04:20:48", quantity: nil>]"
```

My controller where i loop through a set of search parameters and search for a specific category:

```
              @search = Nmodel.search do
                  fulltext o.category do
                    query_phrase_slop 16
                 end
              end
              @optsolr[count[ = @search.results
```

Results from rails debug:
    ---
    - !!null 
- !!null 
- - !ruby/object:Nmodel
      attributes:
      id: 44
      name: !!null 
      price: !!null 
      expiration: 2012-02-22
      category: ! 'Life '
      description: my description text
      user_id: 3
      created_at: 2012-02-22 04:20:48.048506000Z
      updated_at: 2012-02-22 04:20:48.048506000Z
      quantity: !!null

Comment: Try using Rails.logger to see what the output of C is or use Ruby Debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess from this `Results from rails debug: --- - <<<<!!null >>>>>- <<<<!!null>>>>> - - <<<<!ruby/object:Nmodel attributes: id: 44`.. it returning two empty record and one valid record.

Try this.

```
   <ul>Test Search:       
        <% @optsolr.delete_if{|ele| ele.blank?}.each do |c| %>
          <li>
        <%= c.description %>
          </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility...the sunspot search is returning an ID for an object that no longer exists in the database.  This can happen, especially in development, if you have indexed an object and then deleted the row from the database (maybe by dropping the db?) without deleting it from Solr.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I checked the dev DB... the row does exist.  For good measure i also reindexed sunspot... no change

Comment: The issue is with the array that is created in my loop.  Thanks for your help.